# Draw traced lines to illustrate Pedestrian routing in HERE SDK Lite Edition

Tags: heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

So i was wondering if this edition is able to do such a thing. Currently, im drawing a bus route in blue with illustrated waypoints and that is fine so far.

The passanger needs to walk his way up to the bus stop and i want to illustrate that route as ' traced lines ' or traced dots. is it possible to do it using the object :
*MapPolylineStyle mapPolylineStyle = new MapPolylineStyle();

- [traced lines example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo4l2.png)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
edit in the future :
well for anyone running into this issue as of now. thanks to the user @datasun i was able to update from Heremaps Lite edition to Explorer Edition where they have a lot more features regarding the maps and polylines.

you can pretty much do the following code to achieve dashedLines to illustrate  a pedestrian route :

```
 DashPattern dashPattern = new DashPattern(2,10);
  routeMapPolyline.setDashPattern(dashPattern);
```

where the first parameter means firstGapLength and the second firstDashLength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashed line rendering is not supported by the *Lite Edition*.

Consider to switch to the *Explore Edition* and check the `DashPattern` for [MapPolyLines](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-explore/api_reference/com/here/sdk/mapview/MapPolyline.html). The *Explore Edition* has the same APIs, but more features. Only the `MapViewLite` needs to be replaced by a `MapView` instance.

Comment: do you know if explore edition costs anything or if its too rough on low end phones ?

Comment: It works fine, also on lower end phones. The recommended device range is shown in the doc, and it covers mostly every device from the last 7 years. The Explore Edition is free (with the Freemium plan).